# How to automaticly update some thing after user pay with paypal

Tags: php, paypal

i am working on a project. Its a php website, and it will have premium account and free account.

My question is how do i make a php script automatically run after a user has payed with paypal  to update their status?  or is there any other way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for [PayPal's IPN system](https://www.paypal.com/ipn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to PayPal's [documentation](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside),

```
"When a customer makes a payment to you or a payment is reversed or refunded, 
PayPal will  post a notification to your server at the URL you specified."
```

You provide them with the page, e.g. www.my-site.com/process.php, and payment should post.
Handle that with

```
if ($_POST["payment"] != ""){

...your code to interact with your database

}
```